# LINQ to entities Child queries where Parent has certain properties

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Using C# and LINQ to entities I have a problem with child and parent entity searching.  In conceptual terms I am trying to get a Collection of IEnumerable children where these children have certain properties and also the parents of these children have certain properties.

In concrete terms I have Routes and Streets which have a many to many relationship.  I am trying to find Streets on a specific Route where the Street has a positive property of LeftNote or RightNote (LeftNote and RightNote are strings and I am searching for strings that are not empty space).

I have the following entities (cut down for clarity)

```
public class Route
{
    public int RouteID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Street> Streets { get; set; }
}

public class Street
{
    public string LeftNote { get; set; }

    public string RightNote { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Route> Routes { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following LINQ expression:

```
var streets = this.repository.Routes
                        .Where(r => r.RouteID == routeId).FirstOrDefault()
                        .Streets
                        .Where(s => s.LeftNote.Length > 0 || s.RightNote.Length > 0);
```

This works perfectly until I run this against entity data where the Route exists but there are no streets that have LeftNotes or RightNotes.  In these cases I get a NullReference exception.  I am trying to find a way to properly express this query which handles the absence of Streets with LeftNotes (there should always be a Route which matches routeId.  If not that is a valid exception case and should throw and error).

EDIT: The issue seems to be around null strings rather than anything related to the LINQ construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you actually mean

```
var streets = repository.Streets.Where
       (s => s.Routes.Any(r => r.RouteID == routeId )
             && (s.LeftNote.Length > 0 || s.RightNote.Length > 0));
```

Comment: Routes doesn't have LeftNote and RightNote, instead Streets have them.

Comment: I will test this out as you described

Answer (score 1):

```
var streets = this.repository
                  .Routes
                  .Where(r => r.RouteID == routeId).FirstOrDefault()
                  .Streets
                  .Where(s => s.LeftNote !=null ? s.LeftNote.Length > 0 : false
                          || s.RightNote !=null ? s.RightNote.Length > 0 : false);
```

Havn't tested it, but think it should work.

OR

```
this.repository.Streets(s=>(s.LeftNote.Length >0 || s.RightNote.Length > 0 ) 
                             && s.Routes.routeId==routeId));
```

Comment: The first option compiles and executes but does the opposite of what I want (it returns all streets on the route regardless of the relationship).  The second option needs to find someway to traverse the routes collection.  Routes.routeId is not legal.

Comment: Make both the return values to `false` and it should work now. (See the edit)

Answer (score 1):

Just use String.IsNullOrEmpty().

```
var streets = this.repository
                .Routes
                .Where(r => r.RouteID == routeId).FirstOrDefault()
                .Streets
                .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s.LeftNote) ||
                            !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s.RightNote));
```

Comment: @AlexC FirstOrDefault materializes the query, so the part before runs on the server (in SQL), the part after runs locally.  You can make it more efficient (if necessary) by running the whole query on the server.

Comment: @Phil, how would you suggest going about doing that?

Comment: Well I had a go in my answer.  Not sure if it works exactly as you require.  If you use LINQPad you can see the generated SQL when testing  your LINQ.

Comment: @AlexC, also FirstOrDefault() can by definition return NULL so you would now get a null-ref if the routeId didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
var streets = this.repository.Routes
                             .Where(r => r.RouteID == routeId).FirstOrDefault()
                             .Streets
                             .Where(s => s.LeftNote ? s.LeftNote.Length > 0 : false || s.RightNote ? s.RightNote.Length > 0 : true);
```

**Update**

```
var streets = this.repository.Streets
                             .Where(s => s.Routes.RouteID == routeId && s.LeftNote.Length > 0 || s.RightNote.Length > 0);
```

Update code is after inserting your new code.

The reason to use false first is to force the validation of second or clause. Not sure whether the following works.

Comment: @Flowerking: Sorry, I want to put `?` instead of `??`. Thanks for point this out. I have updated my code.

Comment: This does not compile as you are trying to assign a string to the boolean value of false in s.LeftNote ? s.LeftNote.Length > 0 : false and a string to the boolean true in s.RightNote ? s.RightNote.Length > 0 : true .  I am interested at what you might be hinting as a solution but as it stands this does not make much sense to me.

Comment: `assign a string to the boolean value` How is that? `s.LeftNote.Length>0` is a boolean and so `false` is. I don't understand, please clarify

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be executed in one query

```
IEnumerable<Street> streets = Enumerable.Empty<Street>();
var route = this.repository
                .Routes
                .Where(r => r.RouteID == routeId).FirstOrDefault()

if(route != null && route.Streets.Any())
{
    streets = route.Streets
                   .Where(s => s.LeftNote.Length > 0 
                            || s.RightNote.Length > 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the LINQ expression to this

```
var streets = this.repository.Routes
                  .Where(r => r.RouteID == routeId).FirstOrDefault()
                  .Where(r => r.Streets.Any(s => s.LeftNote.Length > 0 || s.RightNote.Length > 0));
```